# SvelteKit GET API endpoint response.json() throws error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, sveltekit

I'm trying to implement an API endpoint that will fetch data from an external server and feed it to +layout.svelte when the locale is changed (all components are mounted and fully loaded at this point!) but the returned response throws an error when I call .json() on it.

/api/about/+server.js

```
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
import { json  } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export function GET() {
     const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     return json(number);
}
```

+layout.svelte

```
async function handleOnLocaleChange(e) {
    const response = await fetch('/api/about');
    const posts = await response.json();
}
```

https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/get-handlers this is the expected behavior and it works if you try the link too, but it simply doesn't work in my case.

Comment: If you do `console.log(await response.text())` instead, what does it show? Also, just to discard simpler things, what's the path of your `+server.js` relative to the project root?

Comment: @carlosV2 there seems to be some insane bug with my version of sveltekit. I had +server.js in /routes/api/about and it didn't work but the moment I moved it to /routes/api-about it just started working. I have no idea why or how...